# how to handle dates before 2000 through linked server in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql, sql-server, linked-server, firebird2.5

I have linked server established from firebird database to SQL Server 2012 and looks like 
when copying data the dates before 2000 year appears as 30-13-1899, why is that?
anyway to go around this weird behavior? I copy data like this:

```
SELECT * into #temp FROM OPENQUERY ( [test] ,'select * from testtable' )
```

thanks

Comment: show us table ddl and sample data

Comment: source dates are e.g. 30-12-99 or 27-06-11. The first fails somehow and we get 30-12-1899 and the second imports fine to 27-06-2011.

Comment: table ddl means your table structure with column types

Comment: this field has type date with length 3, interesting some other date fields has datetime2 with length 8...

Comment: try to indicate all columns instead of `*` and convert dates to string with full format YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: Firebird dates don't have a length. What are the datatypes in Firebird.